# What response code should we send on exception - WebAPI?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am writing `Web-API` methods. One such method is similar to

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]MyDTO)
{
   //validations 

   try
   {
      InsertInToDB(MyDTO.SomeField);
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      // Say some exception has occurred while inserting in to DB. For eg. SomeField is not a acceptable value.
      // What is the response that I should send to the API user ?
      // Notfound, BadRequest does not seem to be fit in this case.
   }

}
```

Note: `InsertIntoDB` returns a `void`

Now, if some exceptions occur within that method what should be the `HttpStatusCode` that I should send to the user ?

`NotFound` or `Badrequest` responses doesn't seem to fit this case. Any ideas ?

Comment: how about `HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError`

Comment: What about 500 Internal Server Error ?

Comment: @Arjuna @nsgocev: Isn't that the `Internal Server error` is thrown automatically when some un-expected errors occur? In our case, the `exception` clearly states that it is a `DB exception`. So, It doesn't seem to be fine using the `Internal Server Error` to

Comment: There are *plenty* of discussions on HTTP status codes on SO, this case is not unique. The 4xx range is for client errors, 5xx for server errors. If you catch `Exception` without validating input first, you can't distinguish between a client error (missing input) or server error (SQL unreachable).

Comment: @CodeCaster is right. I go into this in detail in my answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Yup. You are correct. Ok, now, assuming if `SQL unreachable or SP is not found/incorrect` what error code should be thrown ?

Comment: Try to use the search :) [HTTP Status Code for database is down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434315/http-status-code-for-database-is-down).

Comment: @CodeCaster: Oops. My bad. Now understood. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Exception you send back depends on a few things.

First, did the user send you bad information? Or did your server screw up?

`4XX` status codes are for when the user screwed up.

#### 4XX:

If the problem is the user sent a badly formatted request, return `400 Bad Request`.

If the problem is you're using POST to determine if a resource exists (say through search), then a `404 Not Found` would be appropriate if a resource they were trying to access wasn't found.

If the problem is that Inserting this value will cause a problem with an existing value (say they have the exact same name and they shouldn't; or some other validation-esque error: `409 Conflict` is appropriate.

#### 5XX

`5XX` status codes are for when your code screwed up. The user did everything right, but you still messed up.

For instance, [if your database is down, a `500` or `503` is appropriate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434315/http-status-code-for-database-is-down).

As an aside, Catching a blanket `Exception` is bad. In this case, if you have different validations, you should create exception classes that can be thrown if there is a Validation error; to differentiate it from the user doing everything write but the code going wrong.

In this case, I'd have:

`ValidationFailedException` -> Web tier Returns 400
`ConflictException` -> Web Tier returns 409
`ItemDoesNotExistException` -> Web Tier returns 404

Note that your data layer can should not have a dependency on the web tier or anything internet related.  That means that you should have internal Exception classes; throw those, and use those to generate the appropriate `HttpException` in your Web Tier.

Comment: The problem is `someField` is not a valid name to be accepted by the DB. So, in this case, what exception should I use ? I cannot choose `Conflict` too :(

Comment: If the user screwed up by entering a value they shouldn't have, it's a bad request(400).  I've edited my answer to provide more detail.  As far as which exception you should use, you should create your own for the data layer, and then in the web tier handle those exceptions to throw web related exceptions (Like `Bad Request`).

Comment: Thanks George. Great explanation. But just one more question: `What if the invoked Stored Procedure in the DB does not exist`? In this case, my DB layer would give me a `SQL exception` and what response-code that I should throw now ??

Comment: Umm. Why would the invoked stored procedure not exist? You're not letting your users type in their own stored procedure names to run, are you?  If you are, we've got deeper problems.  There should *never* be a case where a user knows they're executing a stored procedure, nor should they care.  If your code is wrong, take 10 seconds right now and fix it. Rebuild, redeploy.  You'll have to go into more detail (in your question) about this specific use case; but from what you've told me, we've got bigger problems.

Comment: Thanks George. I will go back a moment and review whats exactly I am doing and come back. Thanks for the insight